# Click event in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

**edit**

my code is now at the end of the document and it works. thx for help.

**question**

I want to call a click function...but when i click on my link the site reloads.

Here is my code:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
var gn = (function(){

var sitelength   = $(window).width(),
    $next        = $('.next'),
    $start       = $('.start'),

    init = function(){
      _scrollto();
      _checkmenu();
    },

    _scrollto = function(){
      $next.on( 'click', function( event ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("body").offset().left+200},1500);
        return false;
      });

      $start.on( 'click', function( event ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("body").offset().left+0},1500);
        return false;
      });
    },

    _checkmenu = function(){
      $(window).scroll(function(e){
        if($(this).scrollLeft()>100 && (!$('#side').hasClass('ac'))){
          $('#side').addClass('ac');
          $('#side').animate({ left : -230 }, 'slow');
          $('#sitenav').animate({ left : 0 }, 'slow');
        }

        if($(this).scrollLeft()<100 && $('#side').hasClass('ac')){
          $('#side').removeClass('ac');
          $('#side').animate({ left : 20 }, 'slow');
          $('#sitenav').animate({ left : -50 }, 'slow');
        }
      });
    }

return { init : init };
})();
gn.init();
})(window);
```

but when i exclude the whole click thing in a "$(document).ready(function())" it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $next        = $('.next'),
$start       = $('.start');

      $next.on( 'click', function( event ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("body").offset().left+200},1500);
        return false;
      });

      $start.on( 'click', function( event ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("body").offset().left+0},1500);
        return false;
      });
});
```

can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: The first version of your click functions is binding the click event before the DOM is ready, so the elements does not yet exist. Try running the `gn.init()` function inside a DOM ready function.

Comment: my code is now under the DOM (end of the document) and now it works :) so the DOM is loaded and the element exists. thx

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ready()` function doesn't execute until the DOM is 'ready', meaning the browser has had time to download and parse the rest of your page.

Assuming your code is in the `<head>` tag, in your first example the code will be executed as soon as the browser encounters it. The browser tries to bind the click event to $('.next'), but the element hasn't been created yet, so the event never gets bound.

Wrapping code like this is `$.ready()` is very good practice, so your second example is a much better solution.

Comment: thank you! now my js-code is at the end of my document and it works. thx for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

When you do not wrap your code in `$(function () {...});`, the DOM is not yet fully loaded, when your code is executed and therefore `$('.next')` and `$('.start')` actually apply to no elements.

This happens because today's JS engines are so fast and optimized that they could execute your whole script, before the browser has fully loaded the page.

Comment: thank you! now my js-code is at the end of my document and it works. thx for the explanation

Comment: Just putting your code at the end of the document does not really solve your problem. In the best case it's a workaround, because you are relying on the timing being correct while loading your page, but this may change on every update and in every browser. Some browsers might still execute your code before the DOM is ready. To fix this you have to state explicitly that your code should be executed after the DOM is ready by surrounding it with `$(function () {...});`, e.g. executing on the browser's DOMReady event.

Comment: ohh ok thank you. i wrap my code in $(function(window, undefined) {}); is this ok?